# Opening an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to make sure I've opened up an equation correctly. The equation is as follows:
$${\mathbf{1}} + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{{{\mathbf{x}}_t}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{ \otimes _{k = 0}^{w - 2}{{\mathbf{x}}_{t - k}}}}$$
I opened it like the equation below:
$${\mathbf{1}} + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{{{\mathbf{x}}_t}}} + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{{{\mathbf{x}}_t} \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - 1}}}} + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{{{\mathbf{x}}_t} \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - 1}} \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - 2}}}} +  \cdots  + \frac{{\mathbf{1}}}{{{{\mathbf{x}}_t} \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - 1}} \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - 2}} \otimes  \cdots  \otimes {{\mathbf{x}}_{t - w + 2}}}}$$
Are these two equations equivalent?

P.S.:

- $\otimes$: is the element-wise product operator.
- Bold numbers/variable names: Are vectors
- Vectors have a similar length
- $w$: An arbitrary integer

Comment: Yes, the way you re-wrote it seems correct to me. I'm guessing the quotient of two vectors is also defined component-wise... But it doesn't matter for your question. As far as I can tell, the way you write it is correct.

Comment: It would appear correct. I'm not sure what $\mathbf{1}$ divided by a vector is (I'm guessing it's element-wise division), but it doesn't matter. The use of $\cdots$ is perhaps a tiny bit ambiguous, but your unpacking of it seems by far the most likely option.

Comment: @Oscar Wow, we just wrote basically the same comment :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Indeed! xD

Comment: @Oscar, TheoBendit, Yes, the $\mathbf{1}$ is a ones vector with the same length as $\mathbf{x}_t$ vector. All of the operations are element-wise.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.